# i am working on servlets, having only one deGet and DoPost method. i wrote one new method in that. . how can i access that new method directly?

Tags: java, servlets

I have call this method under doGet. Please help me to get out of this.
This is my own method and I wanted to call this.

```
public void doYourThingHere(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String[] checkedQues = request.getParameterValues("ttom");
        List<String> checkedQuesList = Arrays.asList(checkedQues);
        Map<String, String> preferences = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        if (session.getAttribute("username") != null) {
            List<Question> questionsList = (List<Question>) session
                    .getAttribute("restaurantQuestionList");

            List<Question> questionsListTemp1 = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
                questionsListTemp1.add(questionsList.get(i));
            }
            session.setAttribute("tomtomRestaurantQuestionList1",
                    questionsListTemp1);

            for (Question question : questionsList) {
                String questionId = String.valueOf(question.getId());
                if (checkedQuesList.contains(questionId)) {
                    String answerId = request.getParameter(questionId);
                    // PreferenceDAO.storePreferences(questionId, answerId,
                    // CATEGORY);
                    preferences.put(questionId, answerId);
                    System.out.println("queid : " + questionId + "answerid : "
                            + answerId);

                }
            }

            String username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
            PreferencesProcessor.process(preferences, username);

            RequestDispatcher requestdp = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/table.jsp");
            requestdp.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            RequestDispatcher requestdp = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp");
            requestdp.forward(request, response);
        }

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet  doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Servlets map HTTP request headers to predefined methods, such as doGet(), doPost(), and some others.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

Since your method modifies data, you should call it with POST.

Most simple way is to forward your doPost() to this method:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    doYourThingHere(request, response);
}
```

What will happen usually is that you'll add some routing logic to your doPost like that:

```
public void doPost(...) {
   String action = request.getParameter("action");

   switch (action) {
      case "doSomething":
          doSomething(request, response);
          break;
      case "somethingElse":
          doSomethingElse(request, response);
          break;
      ...
    }
}
```